# Add ASOAnimatedButton library to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, cocoapods

I would like to use `ASOAnimatedButton` library in my project, due to my project is running on *iOS6*, the project breaks when I run it after install the library using *podfile*. I've tested it in a new project, it works fine for iOS6.

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'ASOAnimatedButton'
```

Instead of integrate it by adding the above lines in *Podfile*, how can I add this library into my project by moving related files? Is there a package of files for me to download and add to the project?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to install the library through Cocoapods, alternatively you can add all the file inside folder 'ASOAnimatedButton/Classes/ios' from the repository into your project.